# Dynamically create n number of ec2 instances with Troposphere

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I'm just getting in to EC2, CloudFormation (and Troposphere), etc. I'm trying to start with a simple Selenium Grid to run nightly. Right now, we're using spinning up 12 selenium nodes (each on it's own EC2 instance) when needed. The stacks are only up for a couple hours at a time. It's highly likely that we will need more in the future, so instead of setting the number of nodes statically, I'm trying to set it up so that Jenkins can dynamically increase the number of nodes.

Right now, I've got a simple for loop that looks like it should work just fine - especially after looking at a bunch of examples:

```
for i in range(numNodes):
    instance = ec2.Instance("Node{}".format(str(i)))
    instance.ImageId = Ref(Image)
    instance.UserData = Base64(Join("", userData))
    instance.InstanceType = Ref(NodeSize)
    instance.KeyName = Ref(SSHKey)
    instance.SecurityGroups = [Ref("NodeSecurityGroup")]
    instance.IamInstanceProfile = "SeleniumNode"
    template.add_resource(instance)
```

Full stack trace:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/source/admin/scripts/troposphere/seleniumGrid.py", line 171, in <module>
    print(template.to_json())
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\troposphere\__init__.py", line 543, in to_json
    sort_keys=sort_keys, separators=separators)
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 403, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 403, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\troposphere\__init__.py", line 440, in default
    return obj.JSONrepr()
  File "C:\Users\Sathed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\troposphere\__init__.py", line 223, in JSONrepr
    "Resource %s required in type %s" % (k, rtype))
ValueError: Resource ImageId required in type AWS::EC2::Instance
```

My Image parameter looks like:

```
Image = template.add_parameter(Parameter(
"Image",
    Type="AWS::EC2::Image::Id",  # I even tried setting this to "String"
    Description="AMI To use for all windows grid instances.",
    Default="ami-c06b24a0"  
))
```

I even tried passing everything to the constructor.

```
for i in range(numNodes):
    instance = ec2.Instance("Node{}".format(str(i)),
                            ImageId=Ref(Image),
                            UserData=Base64(Join("", userData)),
                            InstanceType=Ref(NodeSize),
                            KeyName=Ref(SSHKey),
                            SecurityGroups=[Ref("NodeSecurityGroup")],
                            DependsOn=["NodeSecurityGroup", "WindowsHub"],
                            IamInstanceProfile="SeleniumNode")
    template.add_resource(instance)
```

But I'm still getting the same error. I'm sure it's something stupid, but it's become quite irritating. Any thoughts?

Also, I'm getting the error when I try to print the JSON template.

```
print(template.to_json())
```

Troposphere 1.8.2

Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was going to delete the question once I figured out that I am a bonehead... But that little message about deleting "answered questions" for the sake of all mankind, yadda yadda yadda made me feel guilty. Hopefully someone else out there can learn from my mistakes.

As for the answer...

Turns out there's nothing wrong with Troposphere (I assumed it was my fault). I completely forgot about the Selenium Hub, which is it's own instance, but is NOT set up dynamically based on the number of nodes needed. I had only partially added the resources for the hub. You guess it - I forgot to specify the ImageId kwarg. Once I added that (and a few other kwargs), everything worked flawlessly.

Shout out to @phobologic and all of the other Troposphere maintainers. Because of you, I'm able to turn a 2500+ line JSON object into a ~175 line python script that is MUCH easier to maintain!

Comment: Oh great, glad you figured it out.  I'm actually wondering, now, if there might be a way to make that exception point out the title of the object (provided it has one) that is causing the issue, that surely would have helped you with this.  I'll take a look, and thanks for your kind words :)

Comment: BTW, I went ahead and created a PR that should make troubleshooting these kinds of issues easier: https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/pull/597

Answer (score 1):

troposphere maintainer here. At what point are you getting the ValueError?  Can you share the full stack trace?

One thing that likely won't fix this, but I thought I'd point out, is that you don't need to specify each individual attribute of the instance after creation of the object. Instead, you would normally use this code instead:

```
for i in range(numNodes):
    instance = ec2.Instance(
        "Node{}".format(str(i)),
        ImageId=Ref(Image)
        UserData=Base64(Join("", userData)),
        InstanceType=Ref(NodeSize),
        KeyName=Ref(SSHKey),
        SecurityGroups=[Ref("NodeSecurityGroup")],
        IamInstanceProfile="SeleniumNode",
    )
    template.add_resource(instance)
```

You could even shorten it to:

```
for i in range(numNodes):
    instance = template.add_resource(
        ec2.Instance(
            "Node{}".format(str(i)),
            ImageId=Ref(Image)
            UserData=Base64(Join("", userData)),
            InstanceType=Ref(NodeSize),
            KeyName=Ref(SSHKey),
            SecurityGroups=[Ref("NodeSecurityGroup")],
            IamInstanceProfile="SeleniumNode",
        )
    )
```

Anyway, that doesn't seem to be your issue - so if you could share the full stack trace for the error that'd help, as well as the version of both python & troposphere you are using.

Comment: I actually tried shortening it and passing it to the constructor, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, hit return too early. I updated the question with the information you asked for.